# Gunicorn https without Ngix or load balancer

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, gunicorn

I have a small application running on Gunicorn and according to the official documentation, it supports SSL, but I'm having trouble implementing it.

I have created the self-signed certificate using the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

And my Gunicorn configuration looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000" 
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1

# adding ssl support
certfile = 'cert/localhost.crt'
keyfile = 'cert/localhost.key'

debug = True
#loglevel = 'debug'
loglevel = 'info'
logfile = 'log/logs.log'
```

I launch the application with the following command:

```
gunicorn src.wsgi:application
```

The server starts up successfully:

[server starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taNzC.png)

But when trying to connect, it's not possible.

[web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kS3G.png)